# Creating a Temperature class which supports different units (Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, temperature

I'm working on a class to help me to convert between units, and I need to ask about the best way to create this work.

This is my sample code about temperature:

```
        public class Temperature
{
    private double _Celsius = 0;
    public double Celsius
    {
        get { return _Celsius; }
        set
        {
            _Fahrenheit = (value * 9 / 5) + 32;
            _Kelvin = value + 273.15;
        }
    }
    private double _Fahrenheit = 0;
    public double Fahrenheit
    {
        get { return _Fahrenheit; }
        set
        {
            _Celsius = (value - 32) * 5/9;
            _Kelvin = _Celsius + 273.15;
        }
    }
    private double _Kelvin = 0;
    public double Kelvin
    {
        get { return _Kelvin; }
        set
        {
            _Celsius = value - 273.15;
            _Fahrenheit = (_Celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope to know if there is another good one for this class or not?

Comment: what do you mean by a "good one"?

Comment: In the set methods, you are not setting the actual type that is being set.  For example in the Celsius setter, you set _Farenheit and _Kelvin but not _Celsius.

Comment: You should only store one of the values (i.e. Celsius) and compute the others directly in the accessors. This prevents that the state of your object becomes inconsistent.

Comment: Your example is not a converter class, but a type holding a physical unit (temperature in this case). Depending on your needs, you should go with (stateless) conversion classes instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you have *three* fields `_Celsius`, `_Fahrenheit`, `_Kelvin` when just one (say, `_Celsius`) is enough:

```
  public class Temperature {
    private double _Celsius

    public double Celsius {
      get {
        return _Celsius;
      }
      set {
        // Simplest: no validation (e.g. -500 degree is an evident error)
        _Celsius = value;
      } 
    }

    public double Kelvin {
      get { 
        return Celsius + 273.15;
      }  
      set {
        Celsius = value - 273.15;
      } 
    }

    public double Fahrenheit {
      get { 
        return Celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
      }  
      set {
        Celsius = (value - 32) * 5 / 9;
      } 
    }
  }
```

Now let's think on what is the expected way of using your routine? E.g. I want to convert `100` *Fahrenheit* to *Kelvin*:

```
  double result = new Temperature() { Fahrenheit = 100.0 }.Kelvin;
```

a bit wordy and counter-intuitive, right? May be a better choice is to implement a bunch of `static method`s? And do not create any class at all?

```
  public static class Temperatures {
    public static double FahrenheitToCelsius(double value) {...} 

    public static double CelsiusToKelvin(double value) {...}

    public static double FahrenheitToKelvin(double value) {
      return CelsiusToKelvin(FahrenheitToCelsius(value)); 
    }
    ...
  } 

  ...

  double result = Temperatures.FahrenheitToKelvin(100.0);
```

Comment: I see it more like the TimeSpan class.  You have static methods through which to easily create the desired TimeSpan instance, using your preferred unit of measurement (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)), and the resulting TimeSpan instance provides properties through which you can easily retrieve your preferred unit of measurement (myTimeSpan.TotalSeconds).  I could see a similar implementation for a Temperature class being useful.  var myTemp = Temperature.FromCelsius(100.0); var farenheit = myTemp.Farenheit;

Comment: @BTownTKD: It's a good idea and I like it, but in case of `Temperature` class you have to implement *arithmetics* (what if I want to add, say, 10 degrees to the initial Temperature or I have to find a difference between room temperature and boiling point), *comparisons* (I want to have possibility to write `if (t1 >= t2) ...`) and many other things (say, `IComparable<Temperature>`)

Comment: Indeed.  I've submitted an alternate answer to tackle that approach.

Comment: @BTownTKD: I see; when *working intensively* with temperature (not occasionaly convering from Celsius to Kelvin) your approach is a *better* one; when just converting units static method, IMHO, are *enough*. +1

Comment: And a +1 to you, sir!

Answer (score 4):

A temperature is basically a type of "complex number."  It can be measured in different units of measurement, but ultimately you should still be able to compare two different temperatures to determine if they're equal, or if one is "greater than" the other.  You may also want to add two temperatures or subtract them.

I see this class behaving similarly to the .NET-provided [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  Your Temperature class' implementation would choose a single unit of measurement to use privately - let's say Kelvin.  The Temperature then provides "convenience" properties, which provide the temperature in any of your desired units of measurement (Farenheit or Celsius):

```
public class Temperature
{
    private double _kelvin = 0.0;
    public double Kelvin
    { 
        get { return _kelvin; }
        set { _kelvin = value; }
    }

    public double Fahrenheit 
    {
        get { return /* convert Kelvin to Fahrenheit */; }
        set { _kelvin = /* convert Fahrenheit to Kelvin */; }
    }


    public double Celsius
    {
        get { return /* convert Kelvin to Celsius */; }
        set { _kelvin = /* convert Celsius to Kelvin */; }
    }
}
```

Additionally - like the TimeSpan class - you'll want static methods which allow you to quickly and easily create an instance of your Temperature, using whatever "base measurement" unit you prefer at the time:

```
/* Also inside the Temperature class: */
public static Temperature FromKelvin(double kelvin)
{
    var temperature = new Temperature();
    temperature.Kelvin = kelvin;
    return temperature;
}

public static Temperature FromFahrenheit(double fahrenheit)
{
    var temperature = new Temperature();
    temperature.Fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
    return temperature;
}

public static Temperature FromCelsius(double celsius)
{
    var temperature = new Temperature();
    temperature.Celsius = celsius;
    return temperature;
}
```

Using this approach, you wind up with some nice clean usage syntax;

```
var myTemperatureInKelvin = Temperature.FromCelsius(100.0).Kelvin;
```

Finally - to get some *real* use out of such a class - you would want to [implement comparison and arithmetic operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) for equality, greater-than and less-than comparisons, addition, subtraction, etc.  This allows you to very cleanly compare or add multiple temperatures together;

```
var resultInFahrenheit = (Temperature.FromCelsius(100.0) + Temperature.FromKelvin(200.0)).Fahrenheit;
```

Crazy!  And useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you probably don't want to have a load Temperature objects, you just want to convert one number to another one. So I would consider making Temperature a static class i.e.

```
public static Temperature
```

So you could write a method like

```
public static double GetKelvinFromCelsius(double celsius) {
     return (celsius + 273.15);
}
```

Which could be used like:

```
double kelvinTemperature = Temperature.GetKelvinFromCelsius(400);
```

Comment: Having objects in OOP is good.